# Why does this functor's operator() need the trailing const modifier?

Tags: templates, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++, functor, vmat

I am coming back to C++ (or well, technically, Objective-C++) after many years absence, so please bear with me. I am trying to use templates to implement a solution that would otherwise require a ton of cut-and-paste code. The excerpt below shows the basic gist of the effort:

```
namespace {

    using vMAT::DOUBLE;
    using vMAT::SINGLE;
    using vMAT::INT8;
    using vMAT::UINT8;
    using vMAT::INT16;
    using vMAT::UINT16;
    using vMAT::INT32;
    using vMAT::UINT32;
    using vMAT::INT64;
    using vMAT::UINT64;

    typedef void (* swapFn)(void * vector, vDSP_Length vectorLength);

    // Functor used for template arguments.
    template <typename TypeA>
    struct swapbytes {
        swapFn fn;

        swapbytes()
        {
            if      (sizeof(TypeA) == 8) fn = vMAT_byteswap64;
            else if (sizeof(TypeA) == 4) fn = vMAT_byteswap32;
            else if (sizeof(TypeA) == 2) fn = vMAT_byteswap16;
            else if (sizeof(TypeA) == 1) fn = NULL;
            else NSCAssert(NO, @"Oops!");
        }

        void operator()(void * vector, vDSP_Length vectorLength) const
        // ..................................................... ^^^^^ Why?
        {
            if (fn != NULL) fn(vector, vectorLength);
        }
    };

    template <typename TypeA, typename ClassB>
    void
    loadFromOperation(vMAT_MATv5NumericArray * self,
                      vMAT_MATv5ReadOperation * operation,
                      TypeA a,
                      ClassB b)
    {
        swapbytes<TypeA> SwapA;
        long lenC = self.size[0] * sizeof(TypeA);
        TypeA * C = (TypeA *)malloc(lenC);
        long lenD = vMAT_Size_prod(self.size) * sizeof(ClassB);
        self.arrayData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:lenD];
        self.arrayData.length = lenD;
        ClassB * D = (ClassB *)[self.arrayData mutableBytes];
        __block long idxD = 0;
        vMAT_Size123Iterator(self.size, ^(int32_t n, int32_t o, int32_t p) {
            [operation readComplete:C
                             length:lenC];
            if (operation.swapBytes) { SwapA((void *)C, lenC / sizeof(TypeA)); }
            for (int m = 0;
                 m < self.size[0];
                 m++) {
                D[idxD] = C[m];
                ++idxD;
            }
        });
        free(C);
    }

}

- (void)_load_miUINT8_mxDOUBLE_fromOperation:(vMAT_MATv5ReadOperation *)operation;
{
    loadFromOperation(self, operation, UINT8, DOUBLE);
}
```

My question, as I hope is apparent from the comment ending with "Why?", is why is the `const` declaration required here? If it is elided, the compiler complains that there is no method signature matching the call site at `SwapA(...)` in the body of `loadFromOperation`.

I would understand this if `SwapA` were explicitly declared as `const`, but it's not. Obviously it *could* be, since its operation doesn't rely on mutating any state, but that's beside the point.

And while I have another helpful pair of eyes on this code, I'd welcome any style or other critiques a more proficient C++ practitioner might care to offer…

Comment: What on earth is this `^(...) { ... }` syntax? Some lambda extension? Oh wait, this is Objective-C++?

Comment: Yes: The Blocks extension present in Apple's LLVM and GCC compilers. Sorry, I'd forgotten there was a block in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-`__block` variables that are captured by a block, are copied into the block by value when the block is created, and are `const` inside the block. i.e. inside the block, `SwapA` has the type `const swapbytes<TypeA>`.

Comment: Huzzah! That explains it perfectly, thank you! I was starting to think there must be some obscure bug in the compiler… I was totally overlooking how C++ might interact with the Blocks extension.